# Regex: list of base64 value

Tags: javascript, regex, list

I would like to create a regex in Javascript that allow the following rules :

- nothing
- base64 value
- base64,base64,base64,... (undefined number of base64 values separated by comma)

I found a base64 regex : 
/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{4})*(?:|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{3}=)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{2}==)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{1}===))$/

But I don't know how to upgrade it.

Thanks

Comment: What if you get a _valid-looking_ base64 with invalid data in it? Just go and validate the base64 that you get instead...

Comment: Why would anyone have a comma-delimited string of base64 values?

Comment: easy, in URL : /comments/EFFRTER3DD==,24RFFRFDEFE=,R4G5566

Comment: The question was *why*, not *how*.

Comment: **Because** .... they will send a list of IDs (base64 based format) in the API and the request use the comma as a delimiter. That's why

Comment: Identifiers are typically alphanumeric.  Base64 encoding is only necessary if you're dealing with binary data over a text-based medium.  Also, "that's how they're doing it" isn't a reason for doing it that way.

Comment: Anyway... anyone has an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what could be an option is to take you base64 regex, wrap what is between the `^$` in a non capturing group and repeat that with an optional comma.

[`(?!.*,$)^(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{4})*(?:|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{3}=)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{2}==)|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{1}===)),?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NBECrA/1/)

- Assert using a negative lookahead that your string does not end on a comma `(?!.*,$)`
- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Wrap your base64 regex in a non capturing group `(?:` and repeat that `)+`
- Add an optional comma `,?` after the second non capturing group